# how do i add a column to my tableadaptor and not have lags

Tags: c#, winforms, tableadapter

i have a tableadaptor with a few queries. for a table `FS_TASKS`
.
this table has 12 columns and now i want to add 2 more, did the usuals in sql server management, made the column, etc....

now, when i go to update my tableadaptor in VS, my app load time goes from ~2 seconds to ~30+ seconds.

the ONLY thing i changed was my tableadaptors query from

```
SELECT   id, LISTDATE, CATEGORY, TASK, WHO, PRIORITY, DUEDATE, COMPLETEDATE, 
         UDATE, ACTION, HIDDEN, INDEXPATH
FROM     FS_TASKS
```

into this

```
SELECT   id, LISTDATE, CATEGORY, TASK, WHO, PRIORITY, DUEDATE, COMPLETEDATE, 
         UDATE, ACTION, HIDDEN, INDEXPATH, STATUS, STATUSNOTES
FROM     FS_TASKS
```

what can i do to speed up the load time? all i did was add 2  columns to my dataset's tableadaptor

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/95d5b943-3641-4955-acac-287d21760d4f/how-to-update-dataset-xsd-in-vs?forum=winformsdatacontrols

Comment: That shouldn't affect things a whole lot.  How many rows are we dealing with?

Comment: in the thousands. i cant wrap my head around it either. all i did is add 2 columns. i came across this link (see OP) and i can only assume that adding the coulmns break my tableadaptors as that other post has mentioned. thing is, the solution there is exactly how i added my 2 columns

Comment: so what if you try the same query not using a table adapter.. ? does it still take long.. maybe you have a lag in your network..?

Comment: its not lag in populating from the query, its a lag in opening the acutal application, or the winform. i know adding 2 columns wouldnt hang the application and that link is the closest description to my problem

Comment: Your information is spares! It's only a wild guess but could be a problem with the schema of your server and TableAdapter because they are not the same. You can try to remove your TableAdapter and add it again (or add a new one), then the schema of your TableAdapter should be loaded new.